# cancel disk while extracting in rufus

Tags: usb, partitioning, mbr, format, rufus

recently i want to make a bootable disk for my flashdisk. I've done this ton of times, but today while doing so my flashdisk is ejecting by it self. Rufus is stuck at extracting so i cancel the operation. ( still around 400 mb ). But now my flash disk is broken. Here's my rufus log

```
Rufus version: 2.18.1213 (Portable)
Windows version: Windows 10 64-bit (Build 17763)
Syslinux versions: 4.07/2013-07-25, 6.03/2014-10-06
Grub versions: 0.4.6a, 2.02
System locale ID: 0x0409
Will use default UI locale 0x0409
SetLGP: Successfully set NoDriveTypeAutorun policy to 0x0000009E
Localization set to 'en-US'
Found USB 3.0 device 'General USB Flash Disk USB Device' (090C:1000)
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x81
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 16GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 1960, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 0
Disk ID: 0x00000000
read_sectors: Read error [0x00000015] The device is not ready.
  Read: 0, Expected: 512
  StartSector: 0x00000000, nSectors: 0x1, SectorSize: 0x200
Drive does not have an x86 Master Boot Record

Format operation started
Requesting disk access...
Opened \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 for exclusive write access
Requesting lock...
Will use 'K:' as volume mountpoint
Requesting lock...
Analyzing existing boot records...
read_sectors: Read error [0x00000015] The device is not ready.
  Read: 0, Expected: 512
  StartSector: 0x00000000, nSectors: 0x1, SectorSize: 0x200
Drive does not have an x86 Master Boot Record
read_sectors: Read error [0x00000057] The parameter is incorrect.
  Read: 0, Expected: 512
  StartSector: 0x00000000, nSectors: 0x1, SectorSize: 0x200
Volume does not have an x86 Partition Boot Record
Clearing MBR/PBR/GPT structures...
Erasing 128 sectors
Deleting partitions...
Could not delete drive layout: [0x00000015] The device is not ready.
Could not reset partitions
Re-mounted volume as 'K:' after error

Found USB 3.0 device 'General USB Flash Disk USB Device' (090C:1000)
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x81
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 16GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 1960, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 0
Disk ID: 0x00000000
read_sectors: Read error [0x00000015] The device is not ready.
  Read: 0, Expected: 512
  StartSector: 0x00000000, nSectors: 0x1, SectorSize: 0x200
Drive does not have an x86 Master Boot Record
```

i've opened diskpart try to clean but it's failed.
first error where it detected the disk size

```
DiskPart clean has encountered an error: The device is not ready. See the System Event Log for more information.
```

second error

```
Virtual Disk Service error:
There is no media in the device.
```

when i do chkdsk, the disk is in RAW now

note : i don't mind about data loss

update my action

diskpart doing attribute change readonly has no error and effect

this is my list volume

```
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media                                                      
Volume 1         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    499 MB  Healthy                                                       
Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition    232 GB  Healthy    Boot                                               
Volume 3                      FAT32  Partition     99 MB  Healthy    System                                             
Volume 4     D                       Removable       0 B  Unusable
```

diskpart doing create partition primary will return error

```
DiskPart has encountered an error: The device is not ready.                                                             See the System Event Log for more information.
```

this is my event log

```
 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="TPM" Guid="{1b6b0772-251b-4d42-917d-faca166bc059}" /> 
  <EventID>27</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-10-22T14:49:15.783309600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>35672</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="276" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-FMEU808</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="locationCode">0x1e00016d</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_MANUFACTURER">0x494e5443</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_VENDOR_STRING_1">0x496e7465</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_VEDNOR_STRING_2">0x6c000000</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_VEDNOR_STRING_3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_VEDNOR_STRING_4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_VEDNOR_TPM_TYPE">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_FIRMWARE_VERSION_1">0xb0000</Data> 
  <Data Name="TPM_PT_FIRMWARE_VERSION_2">0x49c</Data> 
  <Data Name="DataSize">8</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">1</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="GetTestResult_Data">48</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it, rebooting and reformatting after removing all patitions? If that does not work, the drive is unalvageable.

Comment: I did unplugging and rebooting, but i can't format and removing all the partitions. When i list partition in diskpart, it said there are no partitions on this disk to show